# Spring Boot WebFluxのjUnitテストでonErrorResume()を通ることを確認したい

Tags: spring-boot, junit

いつもお世話になっております。

Spring Boot WebFluxのjUnitテストでonErrorResume()を通ることを確認したいのですが、
Exceptionが発生時にjUnitテストが止まってしまい、パスを通ることが確認できません。
設定など必要な項目があればご教授ください。

### やりたいこと

`repository.hello()` でRuntime Exceptionが発生したときに
onResumeErrorで例外処理が行われていること(ログが出力されること)を確認したい。

### テストコード

```java
public class HealthCheckHandlerTest {

    private HealthCheckHandler handler;

    @Mock
    private Repository repository;

    @Before
    public void setUp(){
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        // テスト用インスタンスの生成
        handler = new HealthCheckHandler(repository);        
    }    

    @Test
    public void testHandleHealthMonitoring異常系1_DBでエラー() {
        // 事前準備
        when(repository.hello()).thenThrow(new RuntimeException("DB接続エラー"));

        // テストの実行
        Mono<ServerResponse> response = handler.handleHealthMonitoring(request);
        response.subscribe(r -> r.statusCode());
    }
}
```

- テスト対象クラス

```java
@Component
public class HealthCheckHandler {

    /**
     * リポジトリ
     */
    private final Repository repository;

    /**
     * コンストラクタ
     *
     * @param repository リポジトリ
     */
    public HealthCheckHandler(
            Repository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

  /**
     * handler
     *
     * @param request
     * @return
     */
    public final Mono<ServerResponse> handleHealthMonitoring(final ServerRequest request) {
        // とりあえずpostgreを呼び出してみてエラーが生じないか確認する
        Mono<Map<String, Object>> postgreOpe = repository.hello();
        // hogehogeは今回割愛
        return Mono.zip(hogehoge, postgreOpe).flatMap(r -> {
            return ServerResponse
                    .ok();
        }).timeout(Duration.ofSeconds(DURATION_TIME)).onErrorResume(t -> {
            logger.error("health checkでエラーを確認しました", t);
            return ServerResponse
                    .status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
                    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .bodyValue("Error\n");
        });
    }
}
```

### 現状どうなるか？

テストコードの最後で `response.subscribe` 呼び出し時に"DB接続エラー" のモックのエラースタックが積みあがって表示される。テストも失敗扱い。タイミングはあってるけど、処理は継続してほしいのだが...

### 試験環境

vs codeに、java plugin その他一式をぶち込んで実施
* 主なプラグイン
  * Maven for Java
  * Java Test Runner
  * Language Support for Java(TM) by Red Hat
など。

Answer (score 0):

`when(repository.hello()).thenThrow(new RuntimeException("DB接続エラー"));`
↓
`when(repository.hello()).thenReturn(Mono.error(new RuntimeException("DB接続エラー")));`